# Firebase: How to put data in a child that's already created with childbyAutoID

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

people in my app sometimes needs to update the status of something. Now can you choose of 2 things: The so called "Rollerbank" is still there or the "Rollerbank" is removed. The users can create a data ref. The id that will be created by childbyAutoID. Now is my question how to get the right child and update some childs with a value. My post:

```
class Post {
    let ref: DatabaseReference!
    var TypeControle: String = ""
    var Stad: String = ""
    var Tijd: String = ""
    var TijdControle: String = ""
    var TijdControleniet: String = ""
    var Latitude: String = ""
    var Longitude: String = ""
    var Extrainformatie: String = ""
    var Staater: String = ""
    var Staaternietmeer: String = ""

    init(TypeControle: String) {
        self.TypeControle = TypeControle
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Stad: String){
        self.Stad = Stad
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Tijd: String) {
        self.Tijd = Tijd
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Latitude: String) {
        self.Latitude = Latitude
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Longitude: String) {
        self.Longitude = Longitude
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Extrainformatie: String) {
        self.Extrainformatie = Extrainformatie
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Staater: String) {
        self.Staater = Staater
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").child("Controletest").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Staaternietmeer: String) {
        self.Staaternietmeer = Staaternietmeer
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(TijdControle: String) {
        self.TijdControle = TijdControle
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(TijdControleniet: String) {
        self.TijdControleniet = TijdControleniet
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }

    init() {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
    {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            TypeControle = value["TypeControle"] as! String
            Stad = value["Stad"] as! String
            Tijd = value["Tijd"] as! String
            Latitude = value["Latitude"] as! String
            Longitude = value["Longitude"] as! String
            Extrainformatie = value["Extrainformatie"] as! String
            Staater = value["Staater"] as! String
            Staaternietmeer = value["Staaternietmeer"] as! String
            TijdControle = value["TijdControle"] as! String
            TijdControleniet = value["TijdControleniet"] as! String

        }
    }

    func save() {
        ref.setValue(toDictionary())
    }

    func toDictionary() -> [String : Any]
    {
        return [
            "TypeControle" : TypeControle,
            "Stad" : Stad,
            "Tijd" : Tijd,
            "Latitude" : Latitude,
            "Longitude" : Longitude,
            "Extrainformatie" : Extrainformatie,
            "Staater" : Staater,
            "Staaternietmeer" : Staaternietmeer,
            "TijdControle" : TijdControle,
            "TijdControleniet" : TijdControleniet

        ]
    }
}
```

Data for the TableViewCell:

```
class ControleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var storyControle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var storyTijd: UILabel!

    var post: Post! {
        didSet {
            storyControle.text = "\(post.Staaternietmeer)"
            storyTijd.text = "\(post.TijdControleniet)"
            storyControle.text = "\(post.Staater)"
            storyTijd.text = "\(post.TijdControle)"

        }
    }
```

How my update button looks like:

```
 @IBAction func Update(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController1 = UIAlertController(title: "Update melden" , message: "De rollerbank", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create the actions
        let RollerbankAction1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Staat er nog steeds", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Ja Pressed")

            self.newStory.Staater = self.Staater
            self.newStory.TijdControle = self.TijdControle
            self.newStory.save()
        }


        let cancelAction1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Staat er niet meer", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Cancel Pressed")

            let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
            let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
            let Tijd = "\(hour) : \(minutes)"

            self.newStory.Staaternietmeer = self.Staaternietmeer
            self.newStory.TijdControleniet = Tijd
            self.newStory.save()


    }

        alertController1.addAction(RollerbankAction1)
        alertController1.addAction(cancelAction1)
        self.present(alertController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This is the Structure that i use. If i run all this code, the new data will go in a other childbyAutoID and thats not what i want. It just needs to update/setvalue in the cleare space named "Staaternietmeer" and "TijdControleniet". Can anybody help me with that?
[image: Structure]

Comment: You need to store your Child name somewhere so you can access it later to update your data

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But how can you store that and update it afterwords?

Answer (score 2):

You would then need to store the Push ID somewhere so that you can reuse it later.

To generate a unique Push ID you would use :

```
Database.database().reference().childByAutoId()
```

And to store it somewhere :

```
let postKey = Database.database().reference().childByAutoId().key
```

And then, say you need a method to share a post for example, and want to add this post to multiple nodes, that's how it may look like :

```
func sharePost(_ postContent: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    guard let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        completion(false)
        return
    }

    let postKey = Database.database().reference().childByAutoId().key

    let postData: [String: Any] = [ "content": "blabla",
                                    "author": currentUserId ]

    let childUpdates: [String: Any] = ["users/\(currentUserId)/posts/\(postKey)": true,
                                       "posts/\(postKey)": postData ]

    Database.database().reference().updateChildValues(childUpdates, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

        guard error == nil else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        completion(true)
    })

}
```

Now to access the unique Push ID later on, you would use :

```
Database.database().reference().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    // Here you get the Push ID back :

    let postKey = snapshot.key

    // And others things that you need :

    guard let author = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "author").value as? String else { return }
    guard let content = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "content").value as? String else { return }

    // Here you store your object (Post for example) in an array, and as you can see you initialize your object using the data you got from the snapshot, including the Push ID (`postKey`) :

    posts.append(Post(id: postKey, content: content, author: author))

})
```